# Javascript get background image offset position

Tags: javascript, css, background-position

I want to have a fullscreen div with a fullscreen centered background image :

```
#fullScreenHome {
    background:url('home.jpg');
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

To keep the background centered this does apply an offset to the background image position.

I want to make the background image move on mousemove without losing the centering effect.

How do i get the offset value OR how to achieve the desired effect without knowing this value ?

Thanks !

Comment: You could use `50%` instead of `center` and start from `50%` and keep track of the change in your JS as you adjust it.

Comment: possible decrease/increase  percent `background-position: n% n%;` on hover

Comment: The comments here weren't very helpful. I too need to get and set the background-position of an element. I tried https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_backgroundposition and even in their example, when I try to change the value in the javascript example from `"top right"` to `"top 100px right"` my offset is completely ignored. Inspecting the resulting background shows the value `background-position: right top;`